# Crash on selectRowIndexes or scrollRowToVisible of NSTableView in 10.10

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

In the while loop, a method to update NSTableView is being called repeatedly once test starts.

```
......
-(void)runtest:(int)iType wellIndex:(int)nWellIndex
{
    bTestRunning[nWellIndex] = TRUE;

    NSNumber *wellIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:nWellIndex];

    [testThread[nWellIndex] release];
    testThread[nWellIndex] = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                         selector:@selector(testThreadMainRoutine:) 
                                           object:wellIndex]; 

    [testThread[nWellIndex] start];
}
......

- (void)testThreadMainRoutine:(id)argument
{ 
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 

    int nWellIndex = [(NSNumber *)argument intValue];

    int nStartIndex, nEndIndex;
    if (nWellIndex == 0)
    {
        nStartIndex = 0;
        nEndIndex = ONEWELL_UUT;
    }
    else if(nWellIndex==1)
    {
        nStartIndex = ONEWELL_UUT;
        nEndIndex = TWOWELL_UUT;
    }
    else
    {
        nStartIndex=TWOWELL_UUT;
        nEndIndex=MAX_UUT;
    }

    // Log library version etc.
    if (nWellIndex == 0)
        NSLog(@"*** Left Well Test Start ***");
    else if(nWellIndex==1)
        NSLog(@"*** Middle Well Test Start ***");
    else 
        NSLog(@"*** Right Well Test Start ***");

    // Run
    int i, j, itemCount, bContinue;
    itemCount = 0;
    int lineCount = [cmdArray count];

    for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
    {
        [strPlog[j] release];
        strPlog[j] = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

    for (i=0; i<lineCount; i++)
    {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.001];

        [self probeForAbortCondition:nWellIndex];

        if ([testThread[nWellIndex] isCancelled])
        {
            bTestStatus[nWellIndex] = ABORT;
            goto TESTTHREAD_EXIT;
        }

        // Is there any UUT available?
        bContinue = 0;
        for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
        {
            if (uutActive[j])
            {
                bContinue = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (bContinue == 0)
        {
            goto TESTTHREAD_EXIT;
        }

        while(bPaused[nWellIndex])
        {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
            [self setTextResult:@"Pause" textColor:[NSColor orangeColor] wellIndex:nWellIndex];
        }
        [self setTextResult:@"Running" textColor:[NSColor orangeColor] wellIndex:nWellIndex];

        // Per Command Line
        CommandLine *cmdLine = [cmdArray objectAtIndex:i];

        // Run UUT independently from this command line
        if ([cmdLine independentRun] == INDEPENDENTRUN_START)
        {
            g_nIndependentStart = i;
            g_nIndependentStop = [self independentRunStopIndex];

            // Dispatch independent thread for each active UUT
            for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
            {
                if (uutActive[j])
                {
                    g_itemCount[j] = itemCount;

                    NSNumber *uutIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:j];
                    [g_uutThread[j] release];
                    g_uutThread[j] = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                        selector:@selector(testThreadUUTRoutine:) 
                                                           object:uutIndex]; 

                    [g_uutThread[j] start]; 
               }
            }

            // Waiting till test abort or UUT thread finish
            while ( 1 )
            {

                [self probeForAbortCondition:nWellIndex];

                // User press button to abort the test
                if ([testThread[nWellIndex] isCancelled])
                {
                    for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
                    {
                        if ([g_uutThread[j] isExecuting])
                        {
                            [g_uutThread[j] cancel];
                        }
                    }
                    bTestStatus[nWellIndex] = ABORT;
                }

                // Wait until all thread exited, then continue remaining test
                bContinue = 0;
                for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
                {
                     if (uutSelected[j])
                    {
                        if ([g_uutThread[j] isExecuting])
                        {
                            bContinue = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            [g_uutThread[j] release];
                            g_uutThread[j] = nil;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // All UUT thread exited
                if ( ! bContinue)
                {
                    break;
                }

                // Select current test row
                if (itemCount != [self maxCurrentItemCount:nWellIndex])
                {
                    itemCount = [self maxCurrentItemCount:nWellIndex];
                    NSArray *objArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:nWellIndex], [NSNumber numberWithInt:itemCount], nil];
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(selectCurrentRow:) withObject:objArray
                                    waitUntilDone:YES];

                }
                if (nWellIndex == 0)
                {
                    [testTable01 display];
                }
                else if(nWellIndex==1)
                {
                    [testTable02 display];
                }
                else
                {
                    [testTable03 display];
                }
           }

            // Test abort or UUT fail and aborted
            if (bTestStatus[nWellIndex] == ABORT)
            {
                goto TESTTHREAD_EXIT;
            }

            if (g_nIndependentStop >= lineCount)
            {
                // All test done
                goto TESTTHREAD_EXIT;
            }
            else
            {
                // Continue remaining test
                i = g_nIndependentStop;
                cmdLine = [cmdArray objectAtIndex:i];
                itemCount = [self maxCurrentItemCount:nWellIndex];
            }
        }

        NSArray *objArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:nWellIndex], [NSNumber numberWithInt:itemCount], nil];
    // Select current test row
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(selectCurrentRow:) withObject:objArray waitUntilDone:YES];
        });


        NSString *cmdName = [cmdLine valueForKey:@"cmdName"];
        NSString *cmdParam = [cmdLine valueForKey:@"cmdParam"];
        NSString *itemName = [cmdLine valueForKey:@"itemName"];

        // Clear returnArray
        for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
        {
            if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_SKIP) {

                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setUnit:@"NA"];
                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setLowerLimit:@"NA"];
                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setUpperLimit:@"NA"];

                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setCmdResult:@"Skipped"];
                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setTestResult:@"Skipped"];
                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setCmdStatus:SKIPPED];
                continue;
            }


            [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setCmdResult:nil];
            [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setTestResult:nil];
            [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setCmdStatus:FAIL];

            [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setUnit:nil];
            [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setLowerLimit:nil];
            [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setUpperLimit:nil];

    }




    if (nWellIndex == 0)
        NSLog(@"Left Well Executing %d: %@, (%@), %@", i, cmdName, cmdParam, itemName);
    else if(nWellIndex==1)
        NSLog(@"Middle Well Executing %d: %@, (%@), %@", i, cmdName, cmdParam, itemName);
    else
        NSLog(@"Right Well Executing %d: %@, (%@), %@", i, cmdName, cmdParam, itemName);

    if ([cmdName characterAtIndex:0] == '_') // Per UUT command
    {
        // Repeat for all UUT
        for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
        {
            // whether UUT is selected
            if (uutActive[j])
            {
                if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_SKIP) {

                    [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setUnit:@"NA"];
                    [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setLowerLimit:@"NA"];
                    [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setUpperLimit:@"NA"];

                    [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setCmdResult:@"Skipped"];
                    [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setTestResult:@"Skipped"];
                    [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setCmdStatus:SKIPPED];

                    [self saveCmdReading:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdResult]
                             commandLine:i uutIndex:j lineStatus:SKIPPED];

                    // Process test result
                    if (itemName != nil)
                    {
                        [self saveUutResult:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] testResult] testItem:itemName uutIndex:j uutStatus:SKIPPED];
                    }

                    continue;
                }


                // Before Item Test, save timestamp


                    if (itemName != nil) {
                        NSString* timeStamp = [[NSDate date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"\n%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: "
                                                                                  timeZone:nil locale:nil];
                        [strPlog[j] appendFormat:@"%@ START %@", timeStamp, itemName];
                    }

                    // insert to UART log file
                    char buff[1024];
                    NSString *strInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d: %@, (%@), %@", i, cmdName, cmdParam, itemName];
                    sprintf(buff, "\n[Host Executing Cmd]%s\n", [strInfo UTF8String]);
                    [self uartDataLogging:j buffer:buff pureUARTData:NO];




                    [self parseCommand:cmdName parameter:cmdParam lineIndex:i uutIndex:j wellIndex:nWellIndex];

                // Process test result
                    [self saveCmdReading:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdResult] commandLine:i uutIndex:j lineStatus:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdStatus]];

                // Test Item
                if (itemName != nil)
                {
                        [self saveUutResult:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] testResult] testItem:itemName uutIndex:j uutStatus:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdStatus]];
                    }


                    // After Item Test, save timestamp
                    NSString* timeStamp = [[NSDate date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"\n%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: " timeZone:nil locale:nil];
                    [strPlog[j] appendFormat:@"%@ FINISH %@", timeStamp, itemName];
                }

                // Fail Stop/Abort
                if ([[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdStatus] == FAIL)
                {
                    if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_FAILSTOP)
                    {
                        // Stop this UUT test
                        uutActive[j] = 0;

                        // Close UART
                        [self closeSerialPort:j];

                        // shut down UUT USB & Battery Power
                        uutPower(j, 0);
                    }
                    else if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_FAILABORT)
                    {
                        bTestStatus[nWellIndex] = ABORT;
                        goto TESTTHREAD_EXIT;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    else // For all active UUT
    {
        bool skip = false;

        // Before Item Test, save timestamp
        for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
        {
            if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_SKIP) {

                skip = true;

                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setUnit:@"NA"];
                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setLowerLimit:@"NA"];
                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setUpperLimit:@"NA"];

                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setCmdResult:@"Skipped"];
                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setTestResult:@"Skipped"];
                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setCmdStatus:SKIPPED];

                [self saveCmdReading:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdResult] commandLine:i uutIndex:j lineStatus:SKIPPED];

                // Process test result
                if (itemName != nil)
                {
                    [self saveUutResult:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] testResult]
                               testItem:itemName uutIndex:j uutStatus:SKIPPED];
                }


                continue;
            }

// whether UUT is selected
            if (uutActive[j])
            {
                if (itemName != nil)
                {
                    NSString* timeStamp = [[NSDate date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"\n%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: " timeZone:nil locale:nil];
                    [strPlog[j] appendFormat:@"%@ START %@", timeStamp, itemName];
                }

                // insert to UART log file
                char buff[1024];
                NSString *strInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d: %@, (%@), %@", i, cmdName, cmdParam, itemName];
                sprintf(buff, "\n[Host Executing Cmd]%s\n", [strInfo UTF8String]);
                [self uartDataLogging:j buffer:buff pureUARTData:NO];
            }
        }

        if (skip) {
            continue;
        }


        [self parseCommand:cmdName parameter:cmdParam lineIndex:i uutIndex:-1 wellIndex:nWellIndex];

        // Process command return result
        for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
        {
            // whether UUT is selected
            if (uutActive[j])
            {
                [self saveCmdReading:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdResult] commandLine:i uutIndex:j lineStatus:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdStatus]];

                // Process test result
                if (itemName != nil)
                {
                    [self saveUutResult:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] testResult] testItem:itemName uutIndex:j uutStatus:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdStatus]];

                    // After Item Test, save timestamp
                    NSString* timeStamp = [[NSDate date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"\n%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: " timeZone:nil locale:nil];
                    [strPlog[j] appendFormat:@"%@ FINISH %@", timeStamp, itemName];
                }

                // Fail Stop/Abort
                if ([[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdStatus] == FAIL)
                {
                    if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_FAILSTOP)
                    {
                        // Stop this UUT test
                        uutActive[j] = 0;

                        // Close UART
                        [self closeSerialPort:j];

                        // shut down UUT USB & Battery Power
                        uutPower(j, 0);

                    }
                    else if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_FAILABORT)
                    {
                        bTestStatus[nWellIndex] = ABORT;
                        goto TESTTHREAD_EXIT;
                    }
                    else if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_SKIP)
                    {
                        [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setCmdStatus:SKIPPED];
                        [self saveUutResult:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] testResult] testItem:itemName uutIndex:j uutStatus:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdStatus]];
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (itemName != nil)
        itemCount++;
}
```

TESTTHREAD_EXIT:

```
// Turn Off USB & Battery Power
for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
{
    strTestTimeRecord[j] = [[NSString stringWithString:strPlog[j]] retain];
    [strPlog[j] release];
    strPlog[j] = nil;

    // whether UUT is selected
    if (uutActive[j])
    {
        // Close UART
        [self closeSerialPort:j];

        // shut down UUT USB & Battery Power
        uutPower(j, 0);

    }

    //Clear Buffer for Smokey
    [self clearRdBuffStr:j];
 }


// Refresh UI to indicate test result
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(afterRun:) withObject:argument waitUntilDone:NO];

[pool release];
```

}

```
......
-(void)selectCurrentRow:(NSArray*)objArray
{
    int nWellIndex = [[objArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    int itemCount = [[objArray objectAtIndex:1] intValue];

    if (nWellIndex == 0)
    {
        [testTable01 selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:itemCount] byExtendingSelection:NO];
        [testTable01 scrollRowToVisible:itemCount];
    }
    else if(nWellIndex == 1)
    {
        [testTable02 selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:itemCount] byExtendingSelection:NO];
        [testTable02 scrollRowToVisible:itemCount];
    }
    else
    {
        [testTable03 selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:itemCount] byExtendingSelection:NO];
        [testTable03 scrollRowToVisible:itemCount];
    }
}
```

Quite frequently, my app crashes with the crash log below. I am unsure why and can't figure out what the crash message means. Can anyone give me a pointer? Thanks.

```
......
Time Awake Since Boot: 130 seconds

Crashed Thread:        4

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00006d1920bdbec0

VM Regions Near 0x6d1920bdbec0:
MALLOC_NANO            0000608000400000-0000608001c00000 [ 24.0M] rw-/rwx   SM=PRV  
--> 
MALLOC_TINY            00007fb048c00000-00007fb049000000 [ 4096K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: indexGreaterThanIndex:
......
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8640e0dd objc_msgSend + 29
1   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88f44c6a -[NSTableView highlightSelectionInClipRect:] + 728
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88f43e43 -[NSTableView drawRect:] + 1439
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88db5799 -[NSView _drawRect:clip:] + 4238
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88db3e0a -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 1875
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88db420e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2903
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88db420e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2903
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88db420e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2903
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88db420e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2903
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88db420e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2903
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88db420e -[NSView _recursiveDisplayAllDirtyWithLockFocus:visRect:] + 2903
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88db1ca6 -[NSView _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 913
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88db1403 -[NSThemeFrame _recursiveDisplayRectIfNeededIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:topView:] + 333
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88dad79b -[NSView _displayRectIgnoringOpacity:isVisibleRect:rectIsVisibleRectForView:] + 2761
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88d652be -[NSView displayIfNeeded] + 1876
15  com.TopTestDFU                  0x000000010b966d31 -[AppController(TestEngine) testThreadMainRoutine:] + 1825
16  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8f26fdc2 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff89880268 _pthread_body + 131
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff898801e5 _pthread_start + 176
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8987e41d thread_start + 13
```

Answer (score 2):

For a more specific answer, you'll need to provide the code that includes the `while` loop you mentioned.

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` is a memory management bug. Specifically, a message is being sent to an object at an address that's no longer valid (it's been released). I suspect it's a timing issue due to a combination of your repeated requests to refresh the table's selection on the main thread while modifying its data source's collection. Sometimes it's accessing something valid; other times it's not.

Two things concern me: 1) queueing a million UI-related updates in a while loop (instead of sanely throttling your UI updates with, say, a timer), and 2) an odd use of the collection's count as your row indexes (select row 0 if count is 0, meaning there is no row 0? select rows 0-3 if count is 3, meaning only 0-2 are valid rows?).

Try starting a half-second or one-second repeating timer when the updates begin, requesting your table view to update itself, then adjusting its selection each time it's fired (on the main queue, of course). Doing these two together in the same action ensures the table reflects the data so the selection makes sense. Then stop/dismiss/cancel the timer when all updates are complete (if that ever happens; if it's "always updating", definitely choose a longer refresh interval since many-seconds-long updates don't need such frequent refreshes).

As to index range, that's easy enough to adjust - select-all should be a simple range `NSMakeRange(0, collection.count)` (start at the first item, with a length of `count`). Selecting nothing should be an empty set `[NSIndexSet indexSet]`.

**Update**

Also, in your `dispatch_async` call, you're already specifying the main queue, so it's unnecessary and wasteful to also call `-performSelectorOnMainThread:...`. In effect, you're saying "schedule telling the main queue to schedule telling the main queue to do the following..."

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added in the original code in my post above. Please kindly give pointer how to proceed to solve this while I am studying the Apple Documentation.